# One dimensional array results from SQL column

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, db2

```
SELECT col FROM table
```

Say I have this query and I get the following result:

```
array(2) {
0 => array(1){
"COL"=>"value1"
},
1 => array(1){
"COL"=>"value2"
}
}
```

Is there some SQL statement I can use to get this from the same data:

```
array(2) {
0=>"value1",
1=>"value2"
}
```

I'm using zend framework and db2. If it can't be done through SQL, can it be done with Zend?

Thanks

EDIT: I should clarify, I can do this with a loop or a function. I was just wondering if there was a built-in way to do it to save a few lines of code and be all fancy smartpants.

Comment: Which DB2 platform are you using?  DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?

Answer (score 2):

try a custom function like this:-

```
function myfuntion($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
     return FALSE; 
   } 
 $result = array(); 
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
  if (is_array($value)) { 
  $result = array_merge($result, myfuntion($value)); 
   } 
   else { 
   $result[$key] = $value; 
  } 
 } 
return $result; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try the `fetchPairs()` method. That might be what you're looking for, at least in a limited fashion.

> The fetchPairs() method returns data in an array of key-value pairs,
>   as an associative array with a single entry per row. The key of this
>   associative array is taken from the first column returned by the
>   SELECT query. The value is taken from the second column returned by
>   the SELECT query. Any other columns returned by the query are
>   discarded.

You may also try and set the fetch method to `Zend_Db::FETCH_COLUMN`.

> Zend_Db::FETCH_COLUMN: return data in an array of values. The value in
>   each array is the value returned by one column of the result set. By
>   default, this is the first column, indexed by 0.

```
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

in my model:

```
public function getRecords() {
$select = $this->select();

return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

in my controller:

```
$records = $mdl->getRecords();
$recordsArray = $records->toArray();
```

Comment: Not working for me. Says my result is not an object. I'm using: $result = $db->fetchAll($query, array($condition)); Then return $result->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is :

```
 public function my_function() 
   { 

      $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
      $results = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM my_table");
      /* if you want only one row, do something like this*/
      /* $results = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM my_table") */
      return $results;
    }
/* Then maybe in your controller you can call the function 
and */
$results=my_function();
/*make values avelaible to the view*/
$this->view->$results=$results
```

Then inside the view : it depends on what your function resturns:
    case: its fetchAll:

```
<?php foreach ($this->results as $item): ?>
    <?=$item['address']?> /* access fields */
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

case: its fetchRow: No need to use foreach().
I hope it helps.